# Best practice to test your jsf application, for example the login page

Tags: jsf

The normal test of a jsf application starts with the login page, where the backing bean is handling the authentication and so on, at least I did this way so far. I can't figure out a test where I can simulate a bunch of concurrent logins, just to see how the application is doing, a kind of DOS attack.
This kind of test would be interesting for an application bean as well.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of testing is called [stress testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_testing). There is a tool named [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) that allows you to record browser-server interactions (the HTTP requests) and replay them simulating requests from multiple users.